# Form: preview button in popup window, submit button without popup window

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, preview

I have a form and 3 buttons on it: Preview, reset and submit. And I want a new window to pop up when I click on the preview. Unfortunately, it also pops up when I send it

```
<html lang="cs-cz">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styly.css">
 <form name="submit"  method="POST" action="preview.php"  id="formID" onsubmit="target_popup(this)" >

<form name="submit" method="POST" action="mailer.php"   >

<div class="box">

<h1>ODVOZY</h1>

<p class="info"><input type="text" name="name" class="textfield1" placeholder="Jméno a příjmení"/></p>

<p class="info"><input type="text" name="adress" class="textfield1" placeholder="Adresa"/></p>

<p class="info"><input type="text" name="contact" class="textfield1" placeholder="Kontakt"/></p>

<p class="info"><input type="text" name="model" class="textfield1" placeholder="Typ zboží"/></p>

<p class="info"><input type="datetime-local" name="date" class="textfield1" placeholder="Date"/></p>

 <select name="money" class="info1" name="money" method="post">
          <option  value="Vyber způsob platby">Vyber způsob platby</option>
          <option value="Placeno">Placeno</option>
          <option value="Platit doma">Platit doma</option>
          <option value="Placeno jen odvoz">Placeno jen odvoz</option>
          <option value="Jiné (viz poznámky)">Jiné (viz poznámky)</option>
                </select>
             
<select name="city" class="info1" name="city"   method="post" >
          <option  value="Vyber pobočku">Vyber pobočku</option>
          <option value="Dvůr Králové n/L">Dvůr Králové n/L</option>
          <option value="Hořice">Hořice</option>
                </select>

<textarea name="message" class="info1" type="text" cols="20" rows="5"placeholder="Poznámka"></textarea>
 <p>&nbsp;</p> 
          
<input type="submit" name="preview" value="Tisk" class="boxa" /> 
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="boxc" />
<input type="submit" name="mailer" value="Odeslat" class="boxb" formaction="mailer.php" formmethod="POST"  /> 
<script src="script.js"></script>
 </div>
   </form> </form>
</body>
</html>

Here is the Javascript, can you please tell me where it is going wrong
```

var myForm = document.querySelector("#formID");

if(myForm === "#formID" ){
myForm.onsubmit = function() {
var w = window.open('about:blank','Popup_Window','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=300,left = 312,top = 234');
this.target = 'Popup_Window';
}

;

Comment: consider formatting the code in the question as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really badly formatted and I see a lot of issues here

```
</form> </form>
```

for instance.

BTW you have

```
<input type="submit" name="preview" value="Tisk" class="boxa" /> 
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="boxc" />
<input type="submit" name="mailer" value="Odeslat" class="boxb" formaction="mailer.php" formmethod="POST"  />
```

Do you want to submit the form when you click the preview button?
Otherwise change the type ( input type="button" instead of submit).
Add a function on the click and change the js consequently.

```
<input type="button" name="preview"  onclick="openPopup()">

/// JS
function openPopup(){
  var w = window.open('about:blank','...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Unfortunately, now all I get is a white window with no form

Comment: Well if the blank page is "Popup_Window" this is just what you are telling in the openPopup function.

What is this page supposed to show? 
How do you pass the form data to the server/popup page?

Maybe you need to post a minimal, reproducible working example tho check all the thing